# Translation of 오늘 조퇴한다하고 자퇴는 참아줘요

Tags: translation

'Just call in sick and don’t drop out of school'?

[image]

> 오늘 조퇴한다하고
>   자퇴는 참아줘요

Answer (score 3):

조퇴 means leave early.
자퇴 means drop out of school. 
참다 means  "endure, withstand", but used slightly different than English, so that 자퇴는 참아 줘요 means "endure and don't drop out".

So basically it means "Just go home early today, don't drop out"